# Custom Fetch Request not updating the view when adding entries to context

Tags: core-data, swiftui

`CoreData`

I have a one to many relationship of `Ticket` to `Job` respectively.

To show all `Job`s for every `Ticket` I had to avoid using the normal `@FetchRequest`

By doing so my view is not updating when I add a new `Job`

My custom class for `Ticket` has this code for showing all relevant `Job`s

```
 @NSManaged var jobs: NSSet?


public var jobArray: [Job] {
    let set = jobs as? Set<Job> ?? []
    
    return set.sorted {
        $0.wrappedEquipmentName < $1.wrappedEquipmentName
    }
}
```

So when a view is initialized with a ticket, for example:

```
struct MyView: View {
    let ticket: Ticket
    var body: some View {
          

          ForEach(ticket.jobsArray) {  job in 
              Text(job.name)
          }

    }

}
```

I think `Combine` is the answer but I'm unsure of how to about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Observe the ticket

Change `let ticket: Ticket` to

```
@ObservedObject var ticket: Ticket
```

All CoreData objects are `ObservableObjects`

Comment: Awesome fix, that worked on all of my views except one because its using a computed property. Currently looking into it

Comment: Try using a custom [`get{} set{}`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259)